# Batch programing in windows 10, "n" file

Tags: batch-file

Im making a little program and everything works, but at process of application working, it makes "n" file. It doesnt have "type of file" it just says file. But how can i choose where to make that "n" file? And in that n file when i open it it says this:

```
Pinging DESKTOP-29BC2OC [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms 

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have a `ping >null` somewhere written as `ping >n ull`

Comment: Why not show the code  you are using.

Comment: Yup! I have ping localhost -n 1 >n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere within your batch file (or where the batch file itself is being called) it is piping the output of the ping command to a file named "n". Find where and you can change both the path where it creates the file and add a meaningful extension so windows will recognize it's file type (.txt would be a good start).

Check this out the link below for the kind of syntax you are looking for to find where the output file is being created...

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php

the simplest example would read like this (though more likely there is a parameter or two involved [target and output file maybe]):

```
ping DESKTOP-29BC2OC>n
```

with parameters, something like this (oversimplified):

```
ping %1 >%2
```